# Phonograph2:PagingAboveConfiguredLimitNotAllowed in slate

Tags: foundry-slate, foundry-phonograph

I have a dataset synced to phonograph and table search service is used to extract all rows from phonograph. Using this query, i extract 1000 rows, store it in a variable and provide next page token.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2mZM.png)

The logic is working fine when the total rows in table is below 10k. If total row count extends beyond 10k, I get this error.

{"errorCode":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","errorName":"Phonograph2:PagingAboveConfiguredLimitNotAllowed","errorInstanceId":"5ee50e8d-9188-4d2d-935f-f6f6fcd910d2","parameters":{}}